# remove amazon's inbound smtp from my domain

Tags: email, digital-ocean, amazon-ses

I have mail accounts on G Suite, I was trying to Configure Amazon SES to send mails from server.  My sever is located on DigitalOcean.

I don't know how but I think I made a mistake configuring MX records. Then I deleted AWS related records from DigitalOcean and re-configured G Suite MX records.

*Now I can't send emails to that G Suite accounts.*

This is what I get when I check for MX records

[image]

`inbound-smtp.*.amazonaws.com` is still there. I deleted all Amazon SES records from Amazon console, but I can't make my mails work.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it without loosing my mail accounts?

P.S I'm getting this error when I send email to info@kolga.ge: **550 5.1.1 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable**

Answer (score 0):

I think that needed some time.

2 in 10 tries was returning that MX was resolved with `inbound-smtp.*.amazonaws.com` and 8 times it was returning G Suite records.

I just restarted server and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When you do any changes to the zone records which contain NS, A, OR MX Records, it is associated with TTL, After which the records get propogated and updated to all the name servers. While updating any such records, You can set TTL  to low values to get immediate updates after the next TTL cycle, and then revert the TTL to original value. You can check various online tools like https://dnschecker.org to check the  propogation at various domain name servers located worldwide. Thanks!